# "Conduit of Ruin" and "Endless One"

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have a [Conduit of Ruin](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Conduit%20of%20Ruin) on the battlefield and say that I will be casting [Endless One](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Endless%20One) for 10 mana, will the cost reduction of 2 mana from the [Conduit of Ruin](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Conduit%20of%20Ruin)'s effect reduce the X so that the [Endless One](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Endless%20One) is 8/8 or will it remain 10/10?

My thinking is going with X = 10, but I need to make sure.

Then, expanding on that:

If I have 4 x [Conduit of Ruin](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Conduit%20of%20Ruin) on the battlefield, could I cast an 8/8 [Endless One](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Endless%20One) for "free", using only the total cost reduction of 8 mana (from the 4 x [Conduit of Ruin](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Conduit%20of%20Ruin)s) as the "X" casting cost?

Comment: You might think of it like this (summarizing the answers, which is why I put it as a comment which can be temporary): Conduit changes the _cost_, it doesn't change the X.

Comment: Your first and second example process the cards differently. If you reduced X from the amount of mana you want to pay for each Conduit like you did in the first example it would be a -8. The Conduit allows you to increase X without spending more mana, not decrease it from the amount spent. So for 10 mana you can get a 12/12 not an 8/8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your interpretation is correct. From the card rulings:

> Conduit of Ruin’s last ability doesn’t change the mana cost or
> converted mana cost of any spell. It changes only the total cost you
> actually pay.
>
> If you control more than one
> Conduit of Ruin, the last ability of each of them applies only to the
> first creature spell you cast each turn, not to different spells; if you control two Conduits of Ruin, the
> first creature spell you cast each turn will cost {4} less.
>
> If the first creature spell you cast in a turn has {X} in
> its mana cost, you choose the value of X before calculating the
> spell’s total cost. For example, if the first creature spell you cast
> in a turn has a mana cost of {X}{G}, you could choose 2 as the value
> of X and pay {G} to cast the spell.

So, the value that you pick for X is fixed, the only thing that changes is what you actually pay.

Answer (score 0):

You choose a value for X which is then reduced by two colourless mana for each conduit you have on the battlefield.

> If I have a Conduit of Ruin on the battlefield and say that I will be
>   casting Endless One for 10 mana, will the cost reduction of 2 mana
>   from the Conduit's effect reduce the X so that the Endless one is 8/8
>   or will it remain 10/10?

You choose a value for X and then a slew of effects may either increase or decrease the cost. Here is the pertinent rules. It is a bit long but worth the read.

> 601.2a To propose the casting of a spell, a player first moves that card (or that copy of a card) from where it is to the stack. It
>   becomes the topmost object on the stack. It has all the
>   characteristics of the card (or the copy of a card) associated with
>   it, and that player becomes its controller. The spell remains on the
>   stack until it’s countered, it resolves, or an effect moves it
>   elsewhere.
>
> 601.2b If the spell is modal, the player announces the mode choice (see rule 700.2). If the player wishes to splice any cards onto the
>   spell (see rule 702.46), he or she reveals those cards in his or her
>   hand. If the spell has alternative or additional costs that will be
>   paid as it’s being cast such as buyback or kicker costs (see rules
>   117.8 and 117.9), the player announces his or her intentions to pay any or all of those costs (see rule 601.2f). A player can’t apply two
>   alternative methods of casting or two alternative costs to a single
>   spell. **If the spell has a variable cost that will be paid as it’s
>   being cast (such as an {X} in its mana cost; see rule 107.3)**, the
>   player announces the value of that variable. If a cost that will be
>   paid as the spell is being cast includes hybrid mana symbols, the
>   player announces the nonhybrid equivalent cost he or she intends to
>   pay. If a cost that will be paid as the spell is being cast includes
>   Phyrexian mana symbols, the player announces whether he or she intends
>   to pay 2 life or the corresponding colored mana cost for each of those
>   symbols. Previously made choices (such as choosing to cast a spell
>   with flashback from a graveyard or choosing to cast a creature with
>   morph face down) may restrict the player’s options when making these
>   choices.
>
> 601.2f The player determines the total cost of the spell. Usually this is just the mana cost. Some spells have additional or alternative
>   costs. Some effects may increase or reduce the cost to pay, or may
>   provide other alternative costs. Costs may include paying mana,
>   tapping permanents, sacrificing permanents, discarding cards, and so
>   on. The total cost is the mana cost or alternative cost (as determined
>   in rule 601.2b), plus all additional costs and cost increases, and
>   minus all cost reductions. If multiple cost reductions apply, the
>   player may apply them in any order. If the mana component of the total
>   cost is reduced to nothing by cost reduction effects, it is considered
>   to be {0}. It can’t be reduced to less than {0}. Once the total cost
>   is determined, any effects that directly affect the total cost are
>   applied. Then the resulting total cost becomes “locked in.” If effects
>   would change the total cost after this time, they have no effect.

Comment: I think it would improve this answer to specifically say that the value of X is not reduced by the cost reduction mechanisms. Also, you posted 3 large paragraphs of rules quotations and bolded half a sentence (and that half doesn't really say anything alone). I would suggest emphasizing all of the parts that you think are relevant and/or skipping the parts that are irrelevant.